# In The Swearing Jar, is Simon American?

Tags: production-mistakes, the-swearing-jar

[The Swearing Jar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6692776/) is very definitely a Canadian movie. Not just that it was filmed in Canada, and written by a Canadian, but the $5 bill that goes into the titular jar is blue. Later we see loonies and toonies in the jar.

Yet in the scene where Simon is planting bulbs and quoting Shakespeare, he mentions "10th grade", "11th grade" and so on. That's not what Canadians say. It's "Grade 10", "Grade 11" etc. The writer must have known this. It threw me for a moment. Many movies are filmed in Canada but pretend to be in the US. But then they would have used green money, and at $5 a swear, there would have been no coins in the jar.

So why does he use American names for school grades?